# Have a text file created AND have it say it was created if it doesn't exist in batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, echo

So, I want to make a simple line of code that makes it so that the batch file creates a text document, while at the same time, it echos "Achievement Get: Start the game"

```
if not exist "achievements\Start the Game.txt" echo Achievement Get: Start the Game! >> "achievements\Start the Game.txt"
```

(The batch file already has the CD set to the folder location, so it's not because I don't have the full location in there"

Playing around with it, it does create the file, but the batch file never says "Achievement Get: Start the Game!" Instead it says that in the text file that is created when running.

**SHORT VERSION: I want the batch file to create a text file in a folder if the file doesn't already exist, but I also want it to say that the file was created.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the file exits with:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="achievements\Start the Game.txt"
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file found."
else
    echo "$file not found."
fi
```

So this can be written as

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/etc/hosts"
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    ...do what you will

else
    echo "Achievement Get: Start the Game!" > $file
fi
```

EDIT: Note this is Linux

Answer (score 0):

```
if not exist "achievements\Start the Game.txt" copy nul "achievements\Start the Game.txt">nul&echo Achievement Get: Start the Game!
```

You don't say what you want to put in the file. This will creste it zero-length.

The `>nul` suppresses the `file copied` message.

the <kbd>&</kbd> separates commands to be cascaded.

It's also valid to use

```
if not exist "achievements\Start the Game.txt" (
 copy nul "achievements\Start the Game.txt">nul
 echo Achievement Get: Start the Game!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some of my research and came up with this

```
 @echo off
 if not exist "\achievements\Start the Game.txt" goto a
  EXISTS ALREADY
  PAUSE 
  EXIT
        :A
        cd "\achivements"

        echo. 2>  "Start the Game.txt"
        echo Achievement Get: Start the game !
        pause
```

Should work